# skip first value for variable inside of foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, key-value

I have the following function on my site which grabs all the values from `$vid_pix`, and **echos** each them or any associated variables in a `foreach` loop.

Which works fine, however I have a variable - `$Pt` that also gets **echoed** out as well.

Right now though what I am trying to do is - skip the first value in `$Pt`. Also set a static value for the last instance since everything is being moved up 1, leaving the last with no value.

I've tried `array_splice` and `unset`, but it's not skipping the first `$Pt` value.

So if I had -

```
[vp 1]->[5]
[vp 2]->[10]
[vp 3]->[15]
[vp 4]->[20]
```

I would need -

```
[vp 1]->[10]
[vp 2]->[15]
[vp 3]->[20]
[vp 4]->[x]
```

(x = I would have to assign a static value for the last variable.)

My function (stripped down for simplicity)

```
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);
    array_splice($Pt, 0, 1);
    //unset($Pt[0]);
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', true);
    echo $Pt;

    if (last -> $Pt) { // something like this for the last value
        $Pt = '5';
    }
 }
```

To put things into better context, here's the full code for the specific function I'm trying to achieve this within --

```
/*
This is for looping through the uploaded pictures
and sorting them and creating a text file.
*/

$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

$data = "ffconcat version 1.0";
$line = '';

        usort( $vid_pix, function( $a, $b ){
            $aPor = (int) get_post_meta( $a, 'photo_order', true );
            $bPor = (int) get_post_meta( $b, 'photo_order', true );

            if ( $aPor === $bPor ) {
                return 0;
            }

            return ( $aPor < $bPor ) ? -1 : 1;
        } );

        foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
$filename = basename( get_attached_file( $vP ));
$Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', true);
$Por = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_order', true);

$static_value=25;
$array=$Pt;

reset($array);//reset the internal pointer
while(false!==($key=key($array))&&null!==key($array)){//check for current key validity
    $next=next($array);//get the next value and move the pointer
    $array[$key]=$next&&isset($array[$key])?$next:$static_value;//assign the next value to the current key  if valid or the static value if false 
}

var_dump($Por);
var_dump($array);

// try to determine the pic of the placeholder image

if ($vP === end($vid_pix))
        $last_img = $thepath.'/'.$filename;


if ($vstyle === 'Custom') { // if custom timing is chosen

$slide_dur = "\r\nduration ".$Pt;

$filename = basename( get_attached_file( $vP ));
$line .= "file '".$thepath."/".$filename."'".$slide_dur."\r\n";


} else { // if custom timing is NOT chosen

$filename = basename( get_attached_file( $vP ));
$line .= "file '".$thepath."/".$filename."'".$slide_dur."\r\n";

}

$total_items = count($vid_pix);

if ($total_items > 1) { // if total items is more than one

// LAST LINE OF CONCAT TEXT FILE
$lastline = "file '".$last_img."'\r\nduration 2\r\nfile '".$last_img."'";

$isitone = "";
$solopic = "";


// PUT TOGETHER ALL THE LINES FOR THE TEXT FILE
$txtc = $data."\r\n".$line.$lastline;

} else { // if total items is less than one

$isitone = "true";
$solopic = "-loop 1 -probesize 10M -i ".$thepath."/".$filename;

}
}

// SAVE THE TEXT FILE
file_put_contents($thepath.'/paths.txt', $txtc);
```

**UPDATE**

`var_dump` results -

```
string(1) "7"
string(1) "2"
string(1) "6"
string(1) "9"
```

The following link contains the original code which saves the `$Pt` variable -- [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307150/save-attachment-custom-fields-on-front-end)

Comment: how about array_shift() ?

Comment: Or don't drop it and use a for loop instead, iterating the array from the second element to the last.

Comment: @dnFer Because then Im going to have to change other things as well so im trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: your example of what you'd like does not match your explanation.  Your example implies you want to skip the first element, `vp 1`, but your explanation suggests that the output from `get_post_meta` is not what you want.  Please clarify.

Comment: Not skip the first element of $Vp, skip the first $Pt. $Vp is an ID number and $Pt is the number value entered in a form thats associated with that ID. So I want ID # 1 to have the $Pt value from ID # 2 ... makes sense now? @DevDonkey

Comment: Try my answer and let me know whether it helps.

Comment: Have you even seen my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE #1

Try using `array_shift()` like this:

```
foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
    $Pt2 = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);
    $Pt = array_shift( $Pt2 ); // get first value
    $Pt2[] = 'static value';
    var_dump( $Pt, $Pt2 ); // test
}
```

### UPDATE #2

If there's actually just *one* `photo_time` meta for each image/attachment (the attachment IDs are in the `$vid_pix` array), then this should work:

```
$Pt2 = [];
$n = count( $vid_pix );
for ( $i = 0, $j = 1; $i < $n; $i++, $j++ ) {
    $Pt2[] = ( $n === $j ) ? 'static value' :
        get_post_meta( $vid_pix[ $j ], 'photo_time', true );
}
echo implode( ', ', $Pt2 ); // test
```

### UPDATE #3

Add the above (`$Pt2`) code *above*/before this `foreach`, then add the `$i =>`, and change the `$Pt` as you can see below:

```
foreach ($vid_pix as $i => $vP) {
  $filename = basename( get_attached_file( $vP ));
  $Pt = $Pt2[ $i ];
  ...
}
```

Comment: my output looked like this -- `5491: static value<br>5492: static value<br>5493: static value<br>5494: static value<br>5495: static value`

Comment: my output looks like this - `string(2) "10"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}
string(1) "7"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}
string(1) "5"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}` the numbers im using in this example are '10,7,5'

Comment: So the `$Pt2` was `[10, 7, 5]`? How about `$vid_pix`? What are their actual values?

Comment: before the $vid_pix foreach loop, the output of vid_pix is -- `array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "5503"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "5504"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "5505"
}` and $pt2 output -- `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}
<br/>array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}
<br/>array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "static value"
}`

Comment: this is the output -- `7, 5, static value7, 5, static value7, 5, static value`

Comment: What is the output you expected?

Comment: in my function i have this line in the `$vid_pix foreach` -- `$slide_dur = "\r\nduration ".$Pt;` which outputs `duration (Number)` for each image/vid_pix. In that line when I change `$Pt` to your `$Pt2` it outputs -- `duration Array` for each line.

Comment: thank you. It works, now I have one more issue with this code, I'll be posting a new question.

Comment: You're welcome @Rich. But maybe I should add that, you no longer need the `$array` thing as in the code in the current question. (Because the `$Pt2` code already doing the same job.)

Comment: I've cleaned up my code compared to the one in the question thank you. If you have a chance can you please check this question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484842/subtract-array-values-from-each-other-creating-new-array

Comment: Sorry, I actually deleted my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52484842/9217760). Please ask the first commentator to post an answer. =) Cheers!

Comment: your answer was correct though and the answer/code I am using.

Comment: I know it was correct! XD I mean, I'm glad it helped you. =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180739/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-rich).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277887/skip-first-value-for-variable-inside-of-foreach-loop-php/52278650?noredirect=1#comment91798493_52278650), `$Pt` is an array of array. So we simply use [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first value (second level array). And, append an array of static value to the end:

```
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);

    // $Pt is an array of array
    // remove the first key (first array)
    $first_key = array_shift($Pt);

    // Add the static value to end of the array. eg: '5'
    $static_value = '5'; // define static value
    $Pt[] = array($static_value);

    // print them out
    var_dump($Pt);
}
```

Comment: @Rich it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve through your whole code, unless there are more inline comments. Anyways, based on your initial posted requirement, I believe that my could should help you achieve that

Comment: @Rich I have updated the code in sync with your striped down sample code. Please check and let me know!

Comment: I've tried your code and the output of var dump is -- `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "5"
}` but my actual values are - `7, 2, 6, 9, blank`

Comment: @Rich what is the output of var_dump of `$Pt` also ?

Comment: it is --- `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "6"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: @Rich so it is an array of array. And, you want to remove `"7"` (first value) ?

Comment: yes, but the number will vary so Im looking to remove the first number and shift the other values so that key 1 = value 2 , key 2 = value 3 and so forth

Comment: @Rich please check edited answer now. See if it works for you.

Comment: this is my output -- `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180472/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-rich).

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do it in the simplest way?

```
$keys = array_keys($myHashArray);
$values = array_values($myHashArray);
array_shift($keys);
array_shift($values);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Please correct me if I understood it wrong.

Comment: he wants to skip the first value of `get_post_meta`, not the parent array.  I read it like you did.   the question is ambiguous.   Also, why do 2 checks? why not do `if(!$isFirst)`?

Comment: Thank you, I've changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

you could simply proceed like this:

```
$static_value=25;
$array=['vp 1'=>5,'vp 2'=>10,'vp 3'=>15,'vp 4'=>20];

reset($array);//reset the internal pointer
while(false!==($key=key($array))&&null!==key($array)){//check for current key validity
    $next=next($array);//get the next value and move the pointer
    $array[$key]=$next&&isset($array[$key])?$next:$static_value;//assign the next value to the current key  if valid or the static value if false 
}


var_dump($array);
```

output :

```
array(4) {
  ["vp 1"]=>
  int(10)
  ["vp 2"]=>
  int(15)
  ["vp 3"]=>
  int(20)
  ["vp 4"]=>
  int(25)
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with my full code, also with your suggestion but it didnt change anything.

Comment: @Rich i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve with this code however you don't use my code as expected.Either your replace all the `$array` occurrences simply by `$Pt` or you use `$array=&$Pt` instead of simply `$array=$Pt`. Moreover if `$Pt` is an array why are you trying to concatenate it to a string in your code?

Answer (score 0):

How about ?

```
$new_array = array_combine( // to make an array from $keys / values
  array_keys($old_array), // use the old same keys
  array_merge( // the array containing your new values
    array_splice($old_array, 1), // remove the first element
    [$static_value] // add the static value
  )
);
```

Check it in live here : https://repl.it/repls/PerfectUpsetAnalysts

Answer (score 0):

```
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);
$i = 0;
foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
   if($i ==0){
continue;
}
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);
    array_splice($Pt, 0, 1);
    //unset($Pt[0]);
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', true);
    echo $Pt;

    if (last -> $Pt) { // something like this for the last value
        $Pt = '5';
    }
$i++;
 }
```

use this type of counter for skipping value....

Answer (score 0):

As you already know you are getting `photo_time` of each `vid_pix` and in your question I see you need to get `photo_time` of next `vid_pix` for current `vid_pix` and ignore the first `photo_time` which is 5 in provided example and the last `vid_pix` (put something static instead)

```
[vp 1]->[5]
[vp 2]->[10]
...
```

I would need -

```
[vp 1]->[10]
[vp 2]->[15]
...
```

so I think its simple (I use `vip_pix index` as key, you can use whatever)

```
$pt_result = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($vid_pix) - 1; ++$i) {
    $pt_result[$vid_pix[$i]] = get_post_meta($vid_pix[$i+1], 'photo_time', true);
}
$pt_result[$vid_pix[$i]] = 25; //set last one statically
```

Comment: how would i use it with my current code ? $pt_result would replace $Pt?

Comment: @Rich pt_result is an array keeps vip_pix ID as key and poto_time as value. You can change it in the way you want. In first code provided you just echo pt. So you can echo $pt_result array in a loop too. In second code you push it in an array. $pt_result already is an array of pt

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift the array outside the loop since your `$Pt` array has single value. Try the code given below.

```
$newPt = array(); // initialize new array
$vid_pix = get_post_meta($v_Id, 'vid_pix', false);

foreach ($vid_pix as $vP) {
    $Pt = get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);

    // assign to new array
    $newPt[] = $Pt;
}

// remove first value
array_shift( $newPt );

// add static value to end of the array
$static = '5';
$newPt[] = array( $static );

// print updated array
var_dump($newPt);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont understand your answer, and how Im suppose to use it with my code.

Comment: Will the `photo_time` meta have multiple values or single (for each `vid_pix` meta)?

Comment: You are saying your array has values `7, 2, 6, 9, blank`, whether its single `$Pt` value or after `$vid_pix` loop?

Comment: the $Pt values are attached to $vid_pix. So its a array of a array

Comment: Okay I understand it's array of array but can you confirm **first loop** output using `var_dump($Pt); die();` inside `foreach ($vid_pix as $vP)` loop?

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the results of `get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false);` into a function that shifts the values and adds the static value to the end?

```
function shiftPt($input, $end = null) {
    $output = [];
    $prevKey = null;
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if ($lastKey) $output[$lastKey] = $value;
        $lastKey = $key;
    }
    $output[$key] = $end;
    return $output;
}
```

So essentially you could just wrap your existing function like so...

```
$pT = shiftPt(get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false));
```

... and this would leave the last value in the array as null while shifting all of the original values up.

If you wanted to specify the final value (e.g. as `5`) then you could do...

```
$pT = shiftPt(get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false), 5);
```

Comment: will this work if $Pt is an array attached to the $vid_pix array.

Comment: It would - although based on your example code above $Pt isn't "attached" to the $vid_pix array. In your code $Pt is a variable created and populated with the result of get_post_meta($vP, 'photo_time', false) - $vid_pix is irrelevant.

Comment: In my update I added a link to more code to show how $Pt is relevant to $vid_pix

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_slice to remove one set of value from the array and use array_merge to merge it with the "x".

Then you just combine the keys and "new" values.

```
$arr = [
'vp 1'=>[5],
'vp 2'=>[10],
'vp 3'=>[15],
'vp 4'=>[20]];

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$values = array_merge(array_slice($arr, 1), ["x"]);

$new = array_combine($keys, $values);
var_dump($new);
```

This outputs:

```
array(4) {
  ["vp 1"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(10)
  }
  ["vp 2"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(15)
  }
  ["vp 3"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    int(20)
  }
  ["vp 4"]=>
  string(1) "x"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/l7NBa

Comment: yes. I made `$arr = $Pt` and this was the output `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "x"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "x"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "x"
}`

Comment: In that case your question does not show what you got. I used the array from your question and got the output you want as you can see in the link.